# Clojure type hint for Map.Entry

Tags: clojure, type-hinting

What is the syntax for a type hint for `java.util.Map.Entry`, a nested static inner class, in Clojure 1.2?

I tried both `^Map/Entry` and `^Map.Entry`, and neither will compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it!

```
(ns com.example
  (:import [java.util Map Map$Entry]))

(let [^Map$Entry foo ...])
```

and for type-hinting an `Object[]`:

```
(let [^"[Ljava.lang.Object;" foo ...])
```

BTW, that's some **ugly** syntax. Is there a better way?

Comment: In the case of the object array, `objects`.

Answer (score 3):

Inner classes are referred by `$` sign, so, in this case, you can refer to it from Clojure as `Map$Entry`.